# Adjacent words with apostrophes to show possession

Tags: grammar, punctuation, possessives, apostrophe

Is it correct to end adjacent words in `'s` to show possession? For example

> "My neighbour's dog's ball is always in my yard",

or should it be

> "My neighbour dogs ball is always in my yard"

or

> "My neighbour dog's ball is always in my yard"?

Comment: This question is better asked on [ell.se]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct.

> The Earth's oceans' sharks' scales' layers' thickness is hard to measure, due to being minimal.

Is a perfectly acceptable (while confusing and not necessarily true) sentence.

(Just made up, do not take as a fact of shark's scales).

> My neighbour dog's ball

suggests that you have a dog as a next door neighbour - with no owner (but it is wrong).

Comment: I’m pretty sure there are more than one shark in the ocean. And more than one ocean on earth. Plus there are a number of not very natural Saxon genitives in that sentence in general (more natural would be “The thickness of the scale layers on sharks in the Earth’s oceans is hard to measure” _vel sim_). More natural examples of repeated Saxon genitives go through family ties: “My sister’s husband’s brother’s neighbour’s uncle’s dog once caught an alien in Area 51!”. More natural, though no more credible.

Comment: And more than 1 scale and layer, fixed!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet But _the ball of the dog of my neighbor_ sounds unnatural.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Sharks have scales?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fish_scale#Placoid_scales